# How to return false if custom jQuery validation method is passing?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-validate

I created own validation, which is made using json - action is sending response if user email is not unique. Here is action:

```
def checkemail
 respond_to do |format|
  format.jsonr do
    if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists? 
      render :json => {
            :status  => :false,
            }.to_json
    else
      render :json => {
            :status  => :true,
            }.to_json
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Second variant( **don't know how to use** )

```
   def checkemail
   render :nothing
    if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists? 
      return false
    else
      true
    end
  end
```

**I want to write a custom jQuery validation method, and here is code**:

```
   $.validator.addMethod("uniqueness", function(value) {
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr', { email: $('#email').val() }, function(data)  {
       return data.status
    });
}, 'Your email is not unique');
 .....
 "user[email]":{         //here is no error in name
    uniqueness: true
        },
```

**Also tried**

and it constatly tells me that email is not unique.

I think, I'm constanlty sending true in my custom validation method.

**Where is my error ?**

Answer (score 0):

The method should return `true` if the form value is valid. Your method is returning the whole JSON object, not just `data->status`. And since your checkemail function returns `true` if the email is found, your method should return `!data->status` to invert this. Finally, your checkemail function doesn't return any object when the email IS unique; you need an `else` clause to return `:status => false`.

Instead of a custom method, use the built-in remote validation:

```
"user[email]" {
  remote: {
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr",
    type: "get",
    data: {
      email: function() { return $("#email").val(); }
    }
  }
}
```

I think this should be the Ruby-on-Rails script (note: I've never done RoR before, I'm just basing it on examples I found by googling, so I may not have gotten the syntax quite right):

```
def checkemail
 respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists? 
      render :json => false
    else
      render :json => true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I will edit question and you will tell me what I am missing again, ok ?

Comment: Updated question. Still getting the same.

Comment: The problem is that `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. It returns immediately, and the callback function is invoked when the AJAX call returns. Why don't you rewrite your checkemail function to just return true or false, then you can use the built-in remote validation, which deals with this?

Comment: Something like that (look again)? But now I shouldn't use getJson yes ? How to implement this ? How can I pass params dynamically if I won't be using json ?

Comment: You still need to render JSON in the server.

Comment: But it is no need in addMethod now, yes ?

Comment: It has the same issue - constantly says that value is invalid.